# Java/Android regex test if in a string is a link

Tags: java, android

```
Pattern.compile("((http\\://|https\\://|ftp\\://|sftp\\://)|(www.))+((\\S+):(\\S+)@)?+(([a-zA-Z0-9\\.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})|([0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}))(/[a-zA-Z0-9%:/-_\\?\\.'~]*)?");
```

I have this pattern, I'd like to test if there is a link in my string. 
I'd like to linkify those text in a `TextView`.

The code does not work when the link contains a `&` character.

full code:

```
Pattern httpMatcher = Pattern.compile("((http\\://|https\\://|ftp\\://|sftp\\://)|(www.))+((\\S+):(\\S+)@)?+(([a-zA-Z0-9\\.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})|([0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}))(/[a-zA-Z0-9%:/-_\\?\\.'~]*)?");
String httpViewURL  = "myhttp://"; 
Linkify.addLinks(label, httpMatcher, httpViewURL);
```

Comment: Not works?  What does not work?  If you want us to help you, you better give us all the details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is cleaner that using regex:

```
boolean isLink(String s) {
  try {
     new URL(s);
     return true;
  } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
     return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have to use Pattern in this case, sorry. Because I d like to Linkify those text in a TextView

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Patterns.WEB_URL`:

```
public boolean isLink(String string) {
    return Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(string).matches();
}
```

Note that `Patterns` class is available only since API level 8, but you can get its source code here https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/util/Patterns.java

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern httpMatcher = Pattern.compile("((http\\://|https\\://)|(www.))+((\\S+):(\\S+)@)?+(([a-zA-Z0-9\\.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})|([0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}))(/[a-zA-Z0-9%&#-:/-_\\?\\.'~]*)?");
```

this is working now, thanks